# SQL Server ODBC Mirror/Failover Partner

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, failover, mirroring

**Background/Context**

We are in the process of moving our SQL Server 2000 databases to a mirrored SQL Server 2008 R2 server with a witness and automatic failover.  We have both .Net and Access applications running off of these databases, and are testing client redirection on a server failover event.

The .Net apps respond correctly after I added a "Failover Partner" to the connection string. On a failover the app will fail on the next DB request, then move to the mirror server when we restart the app.

**Question**

For the Access applications going through ODBC we are trying to use the SQL Server Native Client 10.0 driver (it looks like the standard driver doesn't support mirroring?) and supplying a mirror server in the settings.

[image: ODBC Mirror Screen]

I'm specifying the database and the failover server name here.  On a failover event the Access application does not seem to be redirected to the mirror server even after an application restart.  Is there anything else I should be doing here to force ODBC to switch to the mirror server, or am I not specifying the mirror server name correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I maintain an Access 2003 application that connects to a pair of SQL Server 2005 servers setup with mirroring.  I use the following connection string which allows the application to connect to the mirror after an application restart:

```
Dim ws As Workspace
Dim db As Database
Dim a As Long

Set ws = DBEngine.CreateWorkspace("MyODBCWorkspace", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase("C:\[pathtodatabase]", True, False, "MS Access;")
For a = 0 To db.TableDefs.Count - 1
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = a
    DoEvents
    If db.TableDefs(a).Connect  "" Then
        db.TableDefs(a).Attributes = TableDefAttributeEnum.dbAttachSavePWD
        db.TableDefs(a).Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Native Client;SERVER=[PrimaryServerName];Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=[MyAppName];WSID=[MyWorkstationName];DATABASE=[SQLServerDatabase];Failover_Partner=[MirrorSQLServerName];"
        db.TableDefs(a).RefreshLink
    End If
Next a
db.Close
ws.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
```

I use this code in a VB launcher app I created that the user double-clicks to launch the Access MDB/MDE.

Alternatively, this is the content of a DSN file we sometimes use to accomplish the same thing:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=SQL Native Client
APP=Microsoft Data Access Components
Trusted_Connection=Yes
SERVER=[ServerFullyQualifiedDomainName]
FAILOVER_PARTNER=[MirrorFullyQualifiedDomainName]
DATABASE=[DatabaseName]
```